# How to create White CustomUIItem with DockPanel root?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, white-framework

I have custom controls set in my window with a complicated structure.
I'd like to create a custom control to incapsulate all logic of this control (with inner grids, buttons, etc.).

In a XAML i've added:

```
<DockPanel AutomationProperties.AutomationId="WidgetName">
```

In a source code i've added:

```
[ControlTypeMapping(CustomUIItemType.Custom)]
public class MyWidget : CustomUIItem{}
```

Add now i'm trying to find the item:

```
_window.Get<MyWidget>("WidgetName");
```

It throws with error that couldn't find control with Custom type and 'WidgetName' name.

Also there will be a set of such controls in a window. Is there something like

```
_window.GetAll<> instead of .Get<>?
```

Comment: Did you find a solution how to handle custom controls? Got the same problem and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Window.Get(SearchCriteria.All);`